# Submitting a form to create an object requires signing up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

So, I have a website that requires the form submission, and I would like to require users to login first or sign up via a modal window. I'm currently using the devise gem for the user authentication. So, in my ResponsesController, I have

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]
```

where create function creates a response object upon user's form submission. This means that when I click on the submit button, it redirects to

```
'/users/sign_in'
```

And I am not sure how I can modify so that it would just show the modal window without having to modify the controller from the devise gem to render format.js.

Anyone know how to show a modal login window when authenticate_user function from devise is called? or know of any example source code I can take a look at, that might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest no doing it modal, but store the request and redirect to singin_path and restore the request after signing in.

```
# application_controller.rb
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |e| # devise has another exception, i think
  if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_path , error: ...
  else
    store_location
    redirect_to login_path, error: ...
  end
end

# some_helper.rb
def redirect_back_or(default, flash)
  back_path = session[:return_to]
  session.delete :return_to
  redirect_to(back_path || default, flash)
end

def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end

# sessions_controller.rb
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  sign_in user
  redirect_back_or(dashboard_path, flash: ...)
end
```

you probably will be storing, not only url, but also params.